# pointers in assembly risc v

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, riscv

I’m studying pointers in risc v assembly, but seeing a code from my professor made me wonder if he made an error, or if I’m missing something. The exercise was about converting from C to Assembly Risc V, and I thought that, because in C, given a variable  `array[N]`, `array`  is a pointer to `array[0]` , in assembly it would be similar and by defining `ARRAY: .dword 1,2,3,4`, `ARRAY`  would be the address of the pointer to `array[0]`, not the address of `array[0]`  directly.

The given C code is (only a snippet, the rest is useless)

```
typedef long long int LONG
LONG vet[10] = {1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3}
LONG *p
void main (){
  p = vet
…
```

and the associated assembly code is

```
VET: .dword 1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3
P: .dword
.text
.globl MAIN

MAIN: la t0, P
      la t1, VET
      sd t1, (t0)
…
```

**MY DOUBTS**

Now: it’s clear to me that the code in C, with `p=vet` is assigning the value inside the vet pointer (so the address of vet[0]) to p, so p now points to the memory cell of vet[0]. But, instead, in assembly, it seems to me that with `la t0, P` we’re assigning the address of P to t0, with `la t1, VET` we’re assigning the address of the vet pointer of t1, and with `sd t1, (t0)` we’re putting the value of the address of vet inside p, so p now points to vet, not to vet[0]

**MY ATTEMPTS AS ANSWER**

So either the code is wrong and should be

```
VET: .dword 1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3
P: .dword
.text
.globl MAIN

MAIN: la t0, P
      la t1, VET
      ld t2, (t1)
      sd t2, (t0)
```

or “VET” in C us actually a symbol for the address of the first element of the array vet[0] and not a the symbol for the address of a pointer, named vet, with inside the address of vet[0]

Comment: Your attempt is loading the frirst element of the array, which is unwanted if you're following the C code

Comment: In C `vet` is an array of int, whose value is an address.  On the other hand, `p` is a variable, whose address is `&p`. In assembly, though, both `VET` and `P` are addresses refering to some data.

Comment: `P: .dword` reserves 0 bytes of storage after the label at that position, since the operand to `.dword` is the empty list.  So the C equivalent is `int *P[0];`.  (Or any type since an empty array of anything is still 0 bytes.) You could do `P: .dword 0` to be equivalent to `int *p;` at global scope: in C, static storage is implicitly initialized to 0 like `int *p = 0;`.

Comment: The right asm instructions are 2x `la` and just `sd`, no `ld`; **static addresses** (e.g. of arrays in static storage like `VET`) **are assemble-time constants and don't have to get loaded from data memory.**

Comment: You can see real compiler output looks like what you were correctly told: https://godbolt.org/z/WKnKo6Y9s .   Also worth looking at asm for something like `VET[2] = 3;` and notice that it compiles to zero loads, only `la` and stores, because the address isn't stored in a pointer anywhere.

Comment: I think part of your confusion may stem from the fact that the word "pointer" is used in two ways, which can usually be distinguished from context, but for a beginner may be confusing.  The word "pointer" can mean an object in memory that contains an address, or it can mean the address itself (also called a "pointer value"). When the name of an array is used in an expression, it is converted to a pointer value.  There is no pointer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … assigning the address of the vet pointer…

`VET` is not a pointer. `VET: .dword 1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3` makes `VET` a label for the data specified by `.dword 1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3`. The value of the label is the address of that data. In assembly, `VET` is the address, not a pointer whose value is the address.

(Also, in C, `vet`, when defined with `LONG vet[10] = {1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3};` is an array, not a pointer. When that array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or the operand of unary `&`, it will be automatically converted to the address of its first element.)

Comment: ok thanks, but once, in C, that array is used in an expression of the type you mentioned (as it is my case, because it’s used in p = vet), it becomes a pointer right? (btw, regarding your first sentence, I used vet in lowercase as the name of the array variable in C, and VET in uppercase the assembly label). Also, before being a pointer, what do you mean by “it’s an array”? There isn’t an “array type” in C, so what is it?

Comment: @selenio34: Using an array in C doesn't create an actual pointer object in static storage, and certainly not inside the array object.  A compiler could invent a pointer *temporary* in automatic storage; in terms of asm, that's the register `t1` holding the array's address after `la t1, VET`.  (This pointer object is anonymous so nothing else can have a reference to it, so the compiler can keep that pointer in a register, not needing to store it to stack space.)

Comment: @selenio34: There are array types in C. `LONG vet[10] = {1,9,3,4,3,15,7,8,2,3};` defines `VET` to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

1. `vet` is an array not pointer. Arrays [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-conversion-aka-decay) to pointers when used in the expressions as values.
2. The compiler does not have to follow the way the program is written. The compiled program has only has to have the same observable behaviour. Your example does not have any so the main will be reduced to return statement.
3. In assembly language there are no pointers only addresses

> what is an array in C, if there’s not an array type?

Of course, it is array type, mentioned many times in the standard.

```
int arr[5];
```

`arr` - decays to pointer to first element of array
`&arr` - decays to pointer to array of 5 elements.

Comment: can you please see the comment under Eric Postpischil answer? what is an array in C, if there’s not an array type?

Comment: It iacts as pointer but it does not have "physical representation" in memory.

Comment: thanks, but so does it mean that it’s just a symbol for us, until it’s used in expressions, and the array pointer to array[0] isn’t yet allocated in memory - while array[0], …, array[N] are allocated already? if yes, how can array, then, know the address of array[0] after you use it in an expression?

Comment: @selenio34 before analyzing emitted code you need to significantly improve your C language knowledge. It is one of the basics - understanding the difference between the array and pointer. Array is a contignous chunk of memory. Pointer references the object in the memory. Array is not a pointer but is acts as pointer lvalue in **expressions**

Comment: It is clear to me the difference between the continuos chunk of memory that is the “real array” and the pointer to it (which is in a different part of memory), but I was always teached that there wasn’t an “array type”, and that, since it’s declaration, the “arr” symbol was always a pointer to the “real array.” Thank you, your comment cleared it up.

Comment: `&arr` does not decay; it is a pointer to an array of five elements.